# como hacer que mi script cuando es ejecutado no borre todos los datos de la tabla, que solo borre las filas con valor menor al escogido en el select

Tags: javascript, html

aca tengo los datos de la tabla

```
        <table id="table" border="1">

            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>999000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>1000,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>132000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>324</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>54</td>
                <td class="vent">98000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>3123</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <select name="filter" class="form-control" id="ageToCheck" onchange="myFunction()">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
          <option value="100000">100000</option>
          <option value="1000000">1000000</option>
      </select>
```

con este script lo que hago es recorrer la tabla con la funcion "Prueba" y con la funcion llamada "MyFunction" hago el filtradro de mostrar solo las filas mayores al valor seleccionado en mi select.

```
    
         var table = document.getElementById("table"), sumVal = 0;
         var aux = [];//the array 

          function prueba(){
          for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){  

          var sumVal = parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
          aux.push(sumVal);//add the value to the end of the array

          }
        }
         prueba();
         
          var ages = aux;
          function checkAdult(age) {
           return age >= document.getElementById("ageToCheck").value;
           }

           function myFunction() {
           document.getElementById("table").innerText = ages.filter(checkAdult);
       
           }
```

mi problema es que a la hora de hacer el filtrado, me borra todos los demas datos del TR osea los datos que estan junto al td que estoy filtrando, y quiero que solo me borre la fila que su valor sea menor al del valor seleccionado al select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo, es filtrar un arreglo de acuerdo al valor del *select* y asignar el resultado como contenido de la tabla.

Creo más conveniente que ocultes o muestres cada fila, para que puedas realizar dos o más cambios en el *select* sin tener que recargar la página. De cualquier forma, dejé comentarios para eliminar las filas que cumplen la condición.

**Nota:** Recuerda que la numeración de filas y celdas comienza en cero, por eso la segunda celda se accede con `row.cells[1]`

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");

function myFunction() {
    // Obtener valor desde el select
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("ageToCheck").value) || 0;
    // Mostrar u ocultar filas
    Array.from(table.rows).forEach(row => {
        // Obtener valor, eliminando comas
        let cellValue = row.cells[1].innerText.replace(',', '');
        row.style.display = (parseInt(cellValue) >= value)
            // Mostrar si el valor es de la celda mayor o igual
            ? ''
            // Ocultar si es menor
            : 'none';
        // Si quieres eliminar, descomenta las siguientes 3 líneas
        //if(parseInt(cellValue) < value) {
        //    row.remove();
        //}
    });
}

// ***** ¿Para qué sirve todo este bloque? *****
var ages = [];  //the array 

function prueba(){
    for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++){  
        var sumVal = parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
        ages.push(sumVal);//add the value to the end of the array
    }
}
prueba();

function checkAdult(age) {
    return age >= document.getElementById("ageToCheck").value;
}
```

```html
        <table id="table" border="1">

            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>999000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>1000,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>132000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>324</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>54</td>
                <td class="vent">98000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>3123</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <select name="filter" class="form-control" id="ageToCheck" onchange="myFunction()">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
          <option value="100000">100000</option>
          <option value="1000000">1000000</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, me ayudaste mucho.